# set value in multiple forms with separate id

Tags: jquery

I'm in great form and I decided it would be filled with jQuery
Each form has its own ID. And I intend to give the name in each entry.

```
 <form id="form1">
    <input name="title" type="text">
    <input name="text" type="text">
<select name=age><option value=1></option><option value=2></option></select>
    </form>
    <form id="form2">
    <input name="title" type="text">
    <input name="text" type="text">
<select name=age><option value=1></option><option value=2></option></select>
    </form>
    <form id="form3">
    <input name="title" type="text">
    <input name="text" type="text">
<select name=age><option value=1></option><option value=2></option></select>
    </form>
    ....
```

I am using the following code but it does not complete the filed

```
$("#form_id [name=title]").val("val");
$("#form_id [name=age]").val("val");
```

Comment: Try $("form input[name=title]").val("val"); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("form input[name=title]").val("val");
$("form select[name=age]").val(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
    <input name="title" type="text">
    <input name="text" type="text">
<select name=age><option value=1>1</option><option value=2>2</option></select>
    </form>
    <form id="form2">
    <input name="title" type="text">
    <input name="text" type="text">
<select name=age><option value=1>1</option><option value=2>2</option></select>
    </form>
    <form id="form3">
    <input name="title" type="text">
    <input name="text" type="text">
<select name=age><option value=1>1</option><option value=2>2</option></select>
    </form>
```

Comment: and what for select box?

Comment: is the OP wanting to fill in  all the `title` fields with the same value?

Comment: @user3243573 See I have updated for the combox how to fill the values...IF you want different values to be updated ...Please feel free to ask

Comment: i build one class for set all edit form . for easy work

Comment: Ahh, I answered the same , before Tushar, why accept his answer if I may ask? :)

Comment: @user3243573 why would you want to set all of the title inputs to the same value and set all of the select boxes to the same value? Why wouldnt you just use one form. It seems more likely that you want to target specific elements in a specific form, this does not do that.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to set the same value for all title's in all forms:

```
$("form input[name=title]").val("val");
```

Does this work for you?

EDIT:

for select fields you should just set default value as

```
<option selected="selected">
```

Also, it's better if you use name = "age" with quotes.

If you must set select values with jQuery you can use

```
$("form select[name=age]").val("1");
```

for instance.

Comment: updated long ago :) you are invited to accept the answer if it answers your question

Comment: I dont get this, why would the OP want to set the title field for several different forms all to the same value?

Comment: I'm not sure, and as far as I am concerned it doesn't matter as long as he really needs to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use classes and jquery's `eq()` :

```js
$(function() {
  
  // change the first `0` to chose a different form
  // change the second `0` to choose a different element
  
  $('.myforms:eq(0) input:eq(0)').val("Hello World")
  
  // for this one, change the third `0` to chose a different select option
  $('.myforms:eq(4) select:eq(0)').prop('selectedIndex', 1);
  // or select by value
  // $('.myforms:eq(4) select:eq(0)').val('2');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="myforms">
<input name="title" type="text">
<input name="text" type="text">
</form>
<form class="myforms">
<input name="title" type="text">
<input name="text" type="text">
</form>
<form class="myforms">
<input name="title" type="text">
<input name="text" type="text">
</form>


<form class="myforms">
    <input name="title" type="text">
    <input name="text" type="text">
    <select name=age><option value=1>Option 1</option><option value=2>Option 2</option></select>
</form>
<form class="myforms">
    <input name="title" type="text">
    <input name="text" type="text">
    <select id="test"name=age><option value=1>Option 1</option><option value=2>Option 2</option></select>
</form>
<form class="myforms">
    <input name="title" type="text">
    <input name="text" type="text">
    <select name=age><option value=1>Option 1</option><option value=2>Option 2</option></select>
</form>
```